# Traverse an raw video more efficiently

Tags: c++, qt, video

I have a raw video file , and i make in qt , an app that reads frame by frame from this file .At large raw files when i press an  button  that goes to the next frame there is a big delay almost one sec .
 Here is my code that returns an frame from raw file :

```
 void RawVideoReader::getFrame(int offset)
{
    std::cout<<"getFrame"<<std::endl;
   file.seek((unsigned long long int)(((unsigned long long int)width * (unsigned long long int)height) * (unsigned long long int)offset));
   QByteArray array = file.read(width * height);

    const std::size_t count = array.size();

    hex = std::unique_ptr<unsigned char>(new unsigned char[count]);
    std::memcpy(hex.get(), array.constData(), count);
}
```

Comment: Instead of constructing a QByteArray, copying out the memory contents, and then throwing it away, you can wrap a QByteArray around your final pointer. That said, the main time is probably spent in disk I/O. Not much you can do about that, except for loading future frames in the background. Have you measured this?

Comment: The type given as template argument to `unique_ptr` is wrong. It should be `unsigned char[]`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can read directly into the buffer you desire - the question is: why do you want to manage this memory buffer using `unique_ptr`? `QByteArray` already does that job. Furthermore, you probably want to keep the same buffer, and not reallocate it over and over.

```
class RawVideoReader : ... {
  QByteArray frame;
  uint8_t *frameData() const { return frame.size() ? static_cast<uint8_t*>(frame.constData()) : nullptr; }
  size_t frameSize() const { return static_cast<size_t>(frame.size()); }
  ...
};

bool RawVideoReader::getFrame(int frameNo) {
  qDebug() << __FUNCTION__;
  frame.resize(width * height * 1);
  file.seek(qint64(frame.size()) * qint64(frameNo));
  auto const hadRead = file.read(frame.data(), frame.size());
  return hadRead == frame.size();
}
```